Use both Intel MPI and MPICH with Clang++
I am using clang to compile an MPI c++ program, and I would like to test it against both MPICH and the intel MPI implementations. I am wondering how to integrate MPI with Clang. Are there MPI wrappers around Clang? I could not find one installed on my system.

Since Intel MPI is based on MPICH, MPICH_CC=clang mpicc works for both implementations. You can see the final compilation call with -show. With older IntelMPI releases you might need to use mpigcc instead of mpicc with the same env variable. For c++ the env variable is MPICH_CXX=clang++.
